# Downloading Android apps from Google Play to PC

Tags: android

I want to download Android apps from Google Play but it only gives an install feature to install directly from web.

**Is there any possibility of downloading these apps to PC and then later transfer it to Android device?**

Comment: Duplicate of [How can I download an APK file from the Play Store?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/12330)

Answer (score 3):

In order to download apps from Google Play directly to your PC, you'll need a third party tool that acts on behalf of your Android Market account. There are several options for tools you can use, you only need to warm up http://google.com and do a search for them.

For instance, there is a [Chrome extension](http://codekiem.com/2012/02/24/apk-downloader/) you can install, see [How to Download APK Files from Google Play to PC](http://www.computric.com/2012/04/how-to-download-apk-files-from-google-play-to-pc/). Basically, the idea is as follows:

- Install the [Chrome extension](http://codekiem.com/2012/02/24/apk-downloader/)
- Start Chrome with SSL warnings disabled
- Enter your Android Market credentials into the Chrome extension
- Enter your Android device ID into the extension

Afterwards, when you visit the marketplace, you'll see an icon in the address bar that you can click to download the APK.

Keep in mind that, to do this, you're installing a third party extension. Always be sure to research the vendor before installing, especially if you're not obtaining the add-on from a reputable site like the Chrome Web Store, Android Marketplace, etc.